# React Testing with withRender

Tags: reactjs, react-router, enzyme, jestjs

I'm trying to test my App component which is nested inside withRouter

```
export default withRouter(App);
```

In my index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
 <BrowserRouter>
   <App client={client}/>
 </BrowserRouter>,

 document.getElementById('root')
);
```

My Test

```
describe("Test: Home page", ()=>{

  const client = {}

  let w = shallow(<App client={client}/>)

  it("Always render the header", ()=>{
     expect(w.find('header').length).toBe(1)
   });
});
```

except the header isn't found and it returns 0 instead of 1
I've looked online but the only other example is grabbing a snapshot whereas I'm trying to check for rendered components

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure, but since you are exporting App with a router, the shallow rendering will only render the router component and not the App component itself. You could try to use the `wrappedcomponent` property of the router to shallow render the component itself and not the router.

[source and example](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using enzyme use `mount` instead of `shallow`.
shallow as name suggest render shallow, which means does not render children, where as mount will completely render with children and your header will be present.